# How to disable javascript code on some jsp pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am using javascript code on my particular specific jsp page, but it runs on all jsp pages in my project. I want js code only on my specific page, not any other, so how do I disable it for another page?

Comment: Add some code here. Are you using templates to generate pages?

Comment: Use javascript namespaces

Comment: You can use Add-ons like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toggle-js/ to toggle js.